# Using sed to fetch date

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file which contains two values for `abc...` keyword. I want to grab the latest date for matching `abc...` string. After getting the date I also need to format the date by replacing `/` with `-`

```
    ---other data
2018/01/15 01:56:14.944+0000 INFO  newagent.bridge BridgeTLSAssetector::setupACBContext() - abc...

2018/02/14 01:56:14.944+0000 INFO  newagent.bridge BridgeTLSAssetector::setupACBContext() - abc...

    ---other data
```

In the above example, my output should be `2018-02-14`. Here, I am fetching the line which contains `abc...` value and only getting the line with latest date value. Then, I need to strip out the remaining string and fetch only the date value.

I am using the following `sed` but it is not working

```
grep -iF "abc..." file.txt | tail -n 1 | sed -e 's/^[^|]*|[^|]*| *\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/' -e 's%/%-%g'
```

Comment: is the data 2018/2/14 or 2018/02/14?  It matters a lot!  The latter is in chronological order when it is in lexiconographic order , the former is not.  You provide both in your question.

Comment: and if it's just 2, did you want it reformatted to 02?

Comment: the correct data contains `2018/02/14`

Comment: the input has 02, or needs it corrected to 02?

Comment: the input always has 02

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
grep -iF "abc..." file.txt | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's#/#-#g'
```

Outputs this:

```
2018-02-14
```

Comment: I like the technique of using `awk` to split around whitespaces.

Comment: what can i do to change it to 2018-02-14

Comment: The file contents you had posted first had it like this: `2018/2/14`, but I see you have edited your post.  `awk` will grab whatever is the first column, separated by spaces, on the line.  So this should work.  Try it on your file.

Comment: By his comment he meant, the desired output is not "2018/2/14", but "2018-02-14".

Comment: @steffen thanks, I had overlooked the dashes. Fixed to do what you requested.

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
$ awk '/abc\.\.\./{d=$1} END{gsub("/", "-", d); print d}' file.txt
2018-2-14
```

Something with sed:

```
tac file.txt | grep -Fi 'abc...' | sed 's/ .*//;s~/~-~g;q'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for `sed` -

```
$: sed -nE ' / abc[.]{3}/x; $ { x; s! .*!!; s!/([0-9])/!/0\1/!g; s!/([0-9])$!/0\1!g; s!/!-!g; p; }' in
2018-02-14
```

> arguments

- `-n` says don't print by default
- `-E` says use extended regexes

> the script

- `/ abc[.]{3}/x;` say on each line with `abc...` swap the line for the buffer
- `$ { x; s! .*!!; s!/([0-9])/!/0\1/!g; s!/([0-9])$!/0\1!g; s!/!-!g; p; }` says on the LAST line(`$`) do the set of commands inside the `{}`.
- - `x` swaps the buffer to get the last saved record back.
- - `s! .*!!;` deletes everything from the first space (after the date)
- - `s!/([0-9])/!/0\1/!g;` adds a zero to the month if needed
- - `s!/([0-9])$!/0\1!g;`  adds a zero to the day if needed
- - `s!/!-!g;` converts the `/`'s to dashes
- - `p` prints the resulting record.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `sed` for matching a part of the date, you can have it match year. month, date and `abc...` in one command.

```
sed -rn 's#([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2}).*abc[.]{3}.*#\1-\2-\3#p' file.txt | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy and more simple try this.

```
cat filename.txt | grep 'abc' | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'
```

As pattern abc always fix as per the given logs. So this will be more easier way to get desire output.